# Is there any way I can run xampp on 11.10 x64?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, xampp

Running xampp says it requires a 32 bit system. Is there a workaround, or a different software I can use??

I am indeed aware of the lamp-server installation available in Ubuntu, and am currently using it.

But I was specifically asking for a integrated LAMP software like xampp which makes it easier to manage the LAMP installation. Currently xampp runs only on x86 systems, and I have a x64 bit install. Hence the question.

Answer (score 4):

It should just work as normal in 64 bit Ubuntu. Running XAMPP as a development server here on my Ubuntu 11.10 x64 without problems. Just follow the installation instructions and it should work out of the box!

Comment: thank you Bart. Was trying to run it out of my home folder, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that you can run any x86 software on an 64 bit system. It will act like a x86 system for the software, so no advantage trough more memory or anything.

I am indeed running XAMPP 1.7.7 on a x64 Ubuntu 11.10 right now, although there is a problem with the MySQL service not starting properly.

Comment: trying to run XAMPP as `~/lampp/lampp start` gives error: _XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system._ Do I need to install a specific library file?

Comment: ahh, found out that the folder location was the culprit. On moving it to /opt, XAMPP works alright! Anyways, thank you Noel!

Answer (score 2):

Issue following command at terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

then start XAMPP as usual

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how XAMPP makes it any easier than it already is. Just apt-get and there you go ("sudo a2enmod userdir; sudo service apache restart" if you prefer having the files in ~/public_html instead of /var/www).

Comment: of course you are right, just that XAMPP keeps everything at one place/folder, thus managing it is easier :)